# Returning copies or clones of collections to prevent mutability

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, clone, mutability

I need to provide a getter method for the values of a HashMap, however I can not allow changes made to the returned Collection or it's elements which will then reflect in the original HashMap I am obtaining the value set from. I am currently doing it like so:

```
public Collection<T> getCollection() {
    Collection<T> collection = map.values();
    return collection;
}
```

Will this adequately achieve what I set out to do, or will changes to the returned Collection still reflect in my HashMap? The reason I ask is because I know any changes to a Collection returned my a Map's .values() method reflect in the original Map. Thanks!

Comment: "will changes to the returned Collection still reflect in my HashMap?" -- have you tried it to see?

Comment: I would, but unfortunately I don't have access to my machine and I'm just writing code up in a text editor.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a substitute for you running your code.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to stack overflow and actually I'm also trying to learn whether I'm achieving the desired functionality correctly, not just substitute for running my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a view of the values you can use `Collections.unmodifiableCollection`

```
public Collection<T> getCollection() {
 Collection<T> view = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(map.values());
 return view;
}
```

This would give you a `view`, ie: clients can't mutate it, but mutations are visible to them.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense :)